# Draw with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I need draw with `QPainter`, but when I try to do it not in

```
void paintEvent( QPaintEvent* )
```

I catch error:

> QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active

Can I use `QPainter` not in void `paintEvent( QPaintEvent* )` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a widget as the paint device for `QPainter`. In this case, `QPainter` can usually only be used within the context of the widget's paint event. The [`QPainter` documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qpaintdevice.html) has the following to say about this:

> **Warning:** When the paintdevice is a
>   widget, QPainter can only be used
>   inside a paintEvent() function or in a
>   function called by paintEvent(); that
>   is unless the
>   Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent widget
>   attribute is set. On Mac OS X and
>   Windows, you can only paint in a
>   paintEvent() function regardless of
>   this attribute's setting.

It is possible to use `QPainter` outside a paint event by setting another paint device for `QPainter`, for example a `QPixmap`.

Comment: I completely missed the word "not" in this question :)

Comment: thank you for reply. Than what can i use for drawing in widget from different methods?

Comment: You don't need to draw from different methods. Put any code for drawing in the paintEvent(). From different methods you can trigger a repaint by calling update(). If you need to paint something different at some point, have your other methods modify some data or flags that are used in the paintEvent() to change how things are rendered.

Comment: For example i have 10 rectangles in my window? they are paint with qpainter. Now i want to click in one of the rectangles and in this rect must draw circle.

Comment: It sounds like the Graphics View framework might suit your needs better than drawing in a widget. But for your last question, you could maintain a list or array of bools for each rectangle and when you determine that one of the was clicked on, set the bool for that rectangle to true. In your paintEvent(), look at each bool as you draw each rectangle and include a circle if the bool is true.